# Table with headings across multiple rows/columns

Tags: output-formatting, grid-layouts, headers-footers

Evaluating

```
TableForm[Table[{x + y, x - y}, {x, 10}, {y, 10}], TableHeadings -> {Table[x, {x, 10}], Table[y, {y, 10}]}]
```

gives me

[image]

What I would like to have is something like

[image]

It doesn't have to be exactly like this but I would like to make clear which variable, $x$ or $y$, changes along rows and which along columns. Is this possible in *Mathematica*?

Also, within each cell, I would like to indicate what the upper and what the lower element represents, i.e. $x+y$ or $x-y$. My first idea was to insert a second header column (perhaps using `Prepend` but that got quite clunky) as shown in the second picture, but if someone can think of a better way, I'm open for suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy to add a horizontal row of headers. You can use [`Prepend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prepend.html) to add vertical headers to the actual data, and then use [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html)with [`Dividers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dividers.html):

```
Grid[{
      {" ", "x y", Sequence @@ Table[x, {x, 10}]}, 
      Sequence @@ MapThread[Prepend /* Flatten, 
                 {
                  Table[Column[{x + y, x - y}], {x, 10}, {y, 10}], 
                  Table[{Column[{"x+y", "x-y"}], x}, {x, 10}]
                 }]
      }, 
    Dividers -> {{2 -> True, 3 -> True}, 2 -> True}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 5):

In case you are not aware, you can add a third level of headings :

```
TableForm[Table[
{x + y, x - y}, {x, 5}, {y, 5}],
 TableHeadings -> {Table[x, {x, 10}], Table[y, {y, 10}],{x+y,x-y}}]
```

Unfortunatly, the result is not satisfactory :

[image]

you may be interested by this trick :

```
fileName=CreateTemporary[];
st=OpenWrite[fileName,FormatType-> OutputForm];
Write[st,TableForm[
 Table[{x + y, x - y}, {x, 5}, {y, 5}],
 TableHeadings -> {Table[x, {x, 5}], Table[y, {y, 5}],{x+y,x-y}},
 TableAlignments-> {Right,Top,Right}],
 ];
Close[st];
Import[fileName]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Or better , thanks to Alexey Popkov's comment :

```
ToString@Format[TableForm[
Table[{x+y,x-y},{x,5},{y,5}],
Table‌​Headings->{Table[x,{‌​x,5}],Table[y,{y,5}]‌​,{x+y,x-y}},
TableAli‌​gnments->{Right,Top,‌​Right}],OutputForm]
```

**Edit (19 August 2019)**

I have put in [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97542/tableform-revisited) , at the very beginning, the code for a function `flatTableForm[]`that does what you need (among other things).

```
flatTableForm[Table[{x + y, x - y}, {x, 10}, {y, 10}], 
 TableHeadings -> {Table[x, {x, 10}], 
   Table[y, {y, 10}], {x + y, x - y}}]
```

[image]

Comment: You can convert `TableForm` into the formatted plain text form using `ToString`: `ToString[TableForm[Table[{x+y,x-y},{x,5},{y,5}],TableHeadings->{Table[x,{x,5}],Table[y,{y,5}],{x+y,x-y}},TableAlignments->{Right,Top,Right}],OutputForm]`.

Comment: Alternative method: `ToString@Format[TableForm[Table[{x+y,x-y},{x,5},{y,5}],TableHeadings->{Table[x,{x,5}],Table[y,{y,5}],{x+y,x-y}},TableAlignments->{Right,Top,Right}],OutputForm]`.